# Running SonarQube analysis via jenkins throwing StackOverFlow error for Spark Scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jenkins, sonarqube, stack-overflow

I have a spark scala application which runs fine without any issues in the jenkins build as well as local build. For one of the method we are using 160 withColumn for adding columns to the dataframe. We have a request for adding two more additional columns. When I added it, everything runs fine from local as well as from EMR, but sonar analysis is throwing stackoverflow error when added those two columns. If I remove it there is no issues. Not sure if the jenkins container has enough resources or not. Tried with different sonar-scanner versions, all are failing, but unit testing, code coverage works fine from local and jenkins, only sonar-scanner is failing. [Jenkins error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWMiX.png)
[Jenkins error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si5IJ.png)

Do I need to rewrite the code to not use withcolumns multiple times ?
Or is this something to fix at Sonar-scanner or jenkins level ?

Is there a better way of adding columns other than using 160 times withcolumn ?

- SonarScanner - 4.6.1.2450
- Scala - 2.12
- sbt  - 1.4.6

```
     val tempDf = slimDf.withColumn("AAA", concat($"post_visid", $"post_visid")).drop("post_visid").drop("post_visid")
          .withColumnRenamed("aaa", "VST_SEQ_NUM")
          .withColumnRenamed("bbb", "PGVW_SEQ_NUM")
          .withColumn("ddd", to_date($"date_time"))
          .withColumn("ccc", date_format($"date_time", "HH:mm:ss"))
          .withColumn("eee", truncateStringUDF($"evar60", lit(255)))
          .withColumnRenamed("fff", "PAGE_EVT_ID")
          .withColumn("ggg", when($"hhh" === 0 || $"hhh" === 70, true).otherwise(false))
          .withColumn("iii", truncateStringUDF($"page_event_var1", lit(1000)))
          .withColumn("jjj", truncateStringUDF($"page_event_var2", lit(1000)))
          .withColumn("kkk", truncateStringUDF($"post_prop11", lit(255)))
          .withColumn("lll", truncateStringUDF($"exclude_hit", lit(255)))
          .withColumn("mmm", truncateStringUDF($"post_prop9", lit(1000)))
          .withColumn("FRST4", when($"daily_visitor" === 0, "N").otherwise("Y")).drop("daily_visitor")
          .withColumn("FRST3", when($"hourly_visitor" === 0, "N").otherwise("Y")).drop("hourly_visitor")
          .withColumn("FRST1", when($"weekly_visitor" === 0, "N").otherwise("Y")).drop("weekly_visitor")
          .withColumn("FRST2", when($"monthly_visitor" === 0, "N").otherwise("Y")).drop("monthly_visitor")
          .withColumn("FRST_QTRLY_VST_IND", when($"quarterly_visitor" === 0, "N").otherwise("Y")).drop("quarterly_visitor")
```

Similar to this, there are total of 160 withcolumn's that adds total of 160 columns to the dataframe

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Scala parsers usually assume that the code consists of small pieces, it's less suitable for code emitted by other programs, or just for extremely deeply nested code in general. In particular, neither the Scala compiler itself, nor Scalameta's parser seem to be stack-safe when confronted with extremely deeply nested terms.

For example, the following much simpler example crashes both `scala` and `sonar-scanner` (which relies on `scalameta`):

```
object Foo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val y = "foo"
      .trim()
      .trim()
      .trim()
      .trim()
      .trim()
      .trim()
      .trim()
      // repeat .trim() ~250 times

    println(y)

  }
}
```

Just cut the gigantic expression somewhere roughly in half, and introduce an additional variable:

```
object Foo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val x = "foo"
      .trim()
      .trim()
      .trim()
      .trim()
      .trim()
      .trim()
      .trim()
      // repeat .trim() ~100 times

   val y = x
     .trim()
     // repeat .trim() ~100 more times

   println(y)

  }
}
```

This then works with both `scala`-interpreter and reasonably recent versions of `sonar-scanner`.

Comment: I will try this and let you know, thanks